# How can I loop for multiple classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a loop instead of adding JavaScript for each element to show the div on first click and hide the div on second click.

Only first div will be shown on clicking first div and second div will be shown on clicking on second div, I don't want to hide any div when clicking on other elements.

I want to show `div` on click and hide it on second click.

```js
$(".d01").click(function() {
  $(".desc1").toggle();
});
$(".d02").click(function() {
  $(".desc2").toggle();
});
$(".d03").click(function() {
  $(".desc3").toggle();
});
$(".four").click(function() {
  $(".d04").toggle();
});
$(".d05").click(function() {
  $(".desc5").toggle();
});
$(".d06").click(function() {
  $(".desc6").toggle();
});
$(".d07").click(function() {
  $(".desc7").toggle();
});
$(".d08").click(function() {
  $(".desc8").toggle();
});
$(".d09").click(function() {
  $(".desc9").toggle();
});
$(".d010").click(function() {
  $(".desc10").toggle();
});
$(".d011").click(function() {
  $(".desc11").toggle();
});
$(".d012").click(function() {
  $(".desc12").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="d01 topic1">Safety</button>
<button type="button" class="d02 topic2">Environment</button>
<button type="button" class="d03 topic3">Climate change</button>
<button type="button" class="d04 topic4">Sustainability</button>
<button type="button" class="d05 topic5">Business strategy</button>
<button type="button" class="d06 topic6">Performance data</button>
<button type="button" class="d07 topic7">Working for You</button>
<button type="button" class="d08 topic8">Working together</button>
<button type="button" class="d09 topic9">Social performance</button>
<button type="button" class="d010 topic10">Human rights</button>
<button type="button" class="d011 topic11">Special reports</button>
<button type="button" class="d012 topic12">Key topics</button>

<div class="desc desc1">Safety</div>
<div class="desc desc2">Environment</div>
<div class="desc desc3">Climate change</div>
<div class="desc desc4">Sustainability</div>
<div class="desc desc5">Business strategy</div>
<div class="desc desc6">Performance data</div>
<div class="desc desc7">Working for You</div>
<div class="desc desc8">Working together</div>
<div class="desc desc9">Social performance</div>
<div class="desc desc10">Human rights</div>
<div class="desc desc11">Special reports</div>
<div class="desc desc12">Key topics</div>
```

Comment: Best is to add a CSS class to all those elements, that is common to them. Otherwise, you can do a jQuery selection on ".one, .two, .three" with commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple selectors instead of writing one by one. for example

```
$('.one, .two, .three').click(function(event){

   //you can use event.target to know which element clicked in case you need 
   console.log('clicked');
 });
```

Since you asked for a common method, this might work

```
<button type="button" class="d01 topic1 btn" data-target="desc1">Safety</button> 
<!-- added a common class 'btn' and data attribute 'target', the target will be your target class name -->
<button type="button" class="d02 topic2 btn" data-target="desc2">Environment</button>



$(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(event){
        var tgtClass = $(event.target).data("target");
        $('.'+tgtClass).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: i want the code as small as possible.

Comment: then you will have to use a single class common to all elements and handle clicks on that  class

Comment: If i'll use same classes than all the buttons will be clicked at same time and their div will show.